# Base64 image conversion in android resulting in corrupted image

Tags: android, json, base64

I need to upload JSON to server so I tried to encode it using base64 and then sending it through JSON but while decoding the image at the server end, the image appears corrupted. I even tried online base64 to image converters, result being the same.

Here is my Activity code where I am encoding the image to base64 after it is choosen from gallery or camera.

```
package com.paaltao.activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.NetworkError;
import com.android.volley.NoConnectionError;
import com.android.volley.ParseError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.ServerError;
import com.android.volley.TimeoutError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.github.mrengineer13.snackbar.SnackBar;
import com.kbeanie.imagechooser.api.ChooserType;
import com.kbeanie.imagechooser.api.ChosenImage;
import com.kbeanie.imagechooser.api.ImageChooserListener;
import com.kbeanie.imagechooser.api.ImageChooserManager;
import com.paaltao.R;
import com.paaltao.classes.SharedPreferenceClass;
import com.paaltao.network.VolleySingleton;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import cn.pedant.SweetAlert.SweetAlertDialog;

import static com.paaltao.extras.Keys.UserCredentials.KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN;
import static com.paaltao.extras.Keys.UserCredentials.KEY_DATA;
import static com.paaltao.extras.Keys.UserCredentials.KEY_EMAIL;
import static com.paaltao.extras.Keys.UserCredentials.KEY_ERROR_CODE;
import static com.paaltao.extras.Keys.UserCredentials.KEY_ERROR_NODE;
import static com.paaltao.extras.Keys.UserCredentials.KEY_HAS_SHOP;
import static com.paaltao.extras.Keys.UserCredentials.KEY_MESSAGE;
import static com.paaltao.extras.Keys.UserCredentials.KEY_OPEN_SHOP;
import static com.paaltao.extras.Keys.UserCredentials.KEY_SELLER_ID;
import static com.paaltao.extras.Keys.UserCredentials.KEY_SIGN_IN;
import static com.paaltao.extras.Keys.UserCredentials.KEY_TOKEN;
import static com.paaltao.extras.Keys.UserCredentials.KEY_VENDOR;
import static com.paaltao.extras.urlEndPoints.BASE_URL;
import static com.paaltao.extras.urlEndPoints.OPEN_SHOP;
import static com.paaltao.extras.urlEndPoints.SIGN_UP;
import static com.paaltao.extras.urlEndPoints.UAT_BASE_URL;

public class OpenShopActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ImageChooserListener {
    Button selectCoverButton;
    private  ImageChooserManager imageChooserManager;
    String imagePath,sellerID,accessToken,encodedImage;
    ImageView coverImageArea;
    private SweetAlertDialog dialog;
    private Bitmap myBitmap;
    private EditText shopName,aboutShop,contactNo,shopAddress,city,state,postalCode,shopURL;
    SharedPreferenceClass preferenceClass;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_open_shop);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) this.findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        this.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        this.setTitle("open a shop!");
        initialize();
        onItemClick();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_open_shop, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_launch){
            if (validationCheck()) {
                sendJsonRequest();
            }
        }

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void initialize(){
        selectCoverButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.select_cover_button);
        coverImageArea = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.shop_cover_image);
        shopName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.shop_name);
        aboutShop = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.about_shop);
        contactNo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.shop_contact);
        shopAddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.shop_street_name);
        city = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.shop_city_name);
        state = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.shop_state);
        postalCode = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.shop_pincode);
        shopURL = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.shop_url);

        preferenceClass = new SharedPreferenceClass(this);
    }

    public boolean validationCheck(){

        if(shopName.getText().toString().length() == 0)
            shopName.setError("Please provide a shop name");
        else if (aboutShop.getText().toString().length() == 0)
            aboutShop.setError("Please provide some info about your shop");
        else if(contactNo.getText().toString().length() == 0 && contactNo.getText().toString().length()>10)
            contactNo.setError("Please provide 10 digit contact number");
        else if(postalCode.getText().toString().length() == 0)
            postalCode.setError("Please provide a postal code");
        else if(shopURL.getText().toString().length() == 0 && shopURL.getText().toString().contains("."))
            shopURL.setError("Please provide a shop url");
        else return true;
        return false;
    }

    public void sendJsonRequest(){
        final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        final JSONObject openShop = new JSONObject();
        try{
            jsonObject.put("accessToken","67drd56g");
            jsonObject.put("merchantName","Arindam Dawn");
            jsonObject.put("userEmail","arindamdawn3@gmail.com");
            jsonObject.put("shopName",shopName.getText().toString());
            jsonObject.put("aboutShop",aboutShop.getText().toString());
            jsonObject.put("contactNo",contactNo.getText().toString());
            jsonObject.put("street",shopAddress.getText().toString());
            jsonObject.put("city",city.getText().toString());
            jsonObject.put("state",city.getText().toString());
            jsonObject.put("country","India");
            jsonObject.put("pincode",postalCode.getText().toString());
            jsonObject.put("shopUrl",shopURL.getText().toString());
            if (encodedImage != null){
            jsonObject.put("coverImage",encodedImage);}
            else
            jsonObject.put("coverImage","");
            openShop.put("openShop", jsonObject);



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        RequestQueue requestQueue = VolleySingleton.getsInstance().getRequestQueue();
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,getRequestUrl(),openShop,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {

                Log.e("error",jsonObject.toString());
                Log.e("json", openShop.toString());
                if (encodedImage != null){
                    Log.e("base64",encodedImage);
                }




                parseJSONResponse(jsonObject);
            }
        },new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                if (volleyError instanceof TimeoutError || volleyError instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                    new SnackBar.Builder(OpenShopActivity.this)
                            .withMessage("No Internet Connection!")
                            .withTextColorId(R.color.white)
                            .withDuration((short) 6000)
                            .show();

                } else if (volleyError instanceof AuthFailureError) {

                    //TODO
                } else if (volleyError instanceof ServerError) {

                    //TODO
                } else if (volleyError instanceof NetworkError) {

                    //TODO
                } else if (volleyError instanceof ParseError) {

                    //TODO
                }

            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }


    public static String getRequestUrl() {

        return UAT_BASE_URL
                + OPEN_SHOP;

    }


    public void onItemClick(){
        selectCoverButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                chooseImageDialog();
                Log.d("TAG","image chooser selected!");
                selectCoverButton.setText("Change cover image");
            }
        });

    }

    public void parseJSONResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        if (jsonObject == null || jsonObject.length() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            JSONObject dataObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject(KEY_DATA);
            JSONObject openShopObject = dataObject.getJSONObject(KEY_OPEN_SHOP);
            JSONObject errorNodeObject = dataObject.getJSONObject(KEY_ERROR_NODE);


            sellerID = openShopObject.getString(KEY_SELLER_ID);
            accessToken = openShopObject.getString(KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN);



            String errorCode = errorNodeObject.getString(KEY_ERROR_CODE);
            String message = errorNodeObject.getString(KEY_MESSAGE);

            if (message.contains("Already Registered")){
                new SnackBar.Builder(OpenShopActivity.this)
                        .withMessage("A shop already exist with this username")
                        .withTextColorId(R.color.white)
                        .withDuration((short) 6000)
                        .show();
            }
            else{
                new SnackBar.Builder(OpenShopActivity.this)
                        .withMessage("Congrats! Shop Created")
                        .withTextColorId(R.color.white)
                        .withDuration((short) 6000)
                        .show();
                preferenceClass.saveVendorLoginSuccess("true");
                Intent intent = new Intent(OpenShopActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }




    public void chooseImage(){
        imageChooserManager = new ImageChooserManager(this,
                ChooserType.REQUEST_PICK_PICTURE);
        imageChooserManager.setImageChooserListener(this);
        try {
            imageChooserManager.choose();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void snapImage(){
        imageChooserManager = new ImageChooserManager(this, ChooserType.REQUEST_CAPTURE_PICTURE);
        imageChooserManager.setImageChooserListener(this);
        try {
            imageChooserManager.choose();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void chooseImageDialog(){
                dialog = new SweetAlertDialog(this, SweetAlertDialog.NORMAL_TYPE);
                dialog.setTitleText("Choose your Cover Image")
                .setContentText("Choose from gallery or take a camera snapshot!")
                .setConfirmText("Gallery")
                .setCancelText("Camera")
                .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sDialog) {
                        chooseImage();
                    }
                })
                .setCancelClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sDialog) {
                        snapImage();
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK &&
                (requestCode == ChooserType.REQUEST_PICK_PICTURE ||
                        requestCode == ChooserType.REQUEST_CAPTURE_PICTURE)) {
            imageChooserManager.submit(requestCode, data);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onImageChosen(final ChosenImage image) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (image != null) {
                    // Use the image
                    imagePath = image.getFileThumbnail();

                    Log.d("TAG","PATH is"+imagePath);

                    myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);

                    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.shop_cover_image);

                    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

                    coverImageArea.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    dialog.hide();
                    dialog.dismiss();



                    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, baos); //bm is the bitmap object
                    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
                    encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                    Log.e("addy",encodedImage);


//
//                    InputStream inputStream = null;//You can get an inputStream using any IO API
//                    try {
//                        inputStream = new FileInputStream(imagePath);
//                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
//                        e.printStackTrace();
//                    }
//                    byte[] bytes;
//                    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
//                    int bytesRead;
//                    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
//                    try {
//                        assert inputStream != null;
//                        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
//                            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
//                        }
//                    } catch (IOException e) {
//                        e.printStackTrace();
//                    }
//                    bytes = output.toByteArray();



                    // image.getFilePathOriginal();
                    // image.getFileThumbnail();
                    // image.getFileThumbnailSmall();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onError(final String reason) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Show error message
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The encoded base64 string that I get in the log is

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

But it is a corrupted image. Help needed !

Comment: try this instead of NO_WRAP...base64String = Base64.encodeToString(byteArr, Base64.DEFAULT);

Comment: I tried it previously, didn't work

Comment: myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
is the above line setting the right image and also use 
myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, baos);

Comment: is this line setting the expected image properly
myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
and also use the below instead of creating a new Bitmap(bm) again
myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, baos);

Comment: Thanks I am trying it

Comment: @DJphy Its still not working. The image path as correct as I am setting the image bitmap in ImageView and its working, but base64 conversion not working.

Comment: okay just post the image that ur trying to convert(it must be downloadable), so i can try it out...

Comment: I tried it with multiple images stored in my mobile sd card. Here's one I've uploaded in dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/s/rkemtuu752lnngx/FB_IMG_1428733015178%5B1%5D.jpg?dl=0

Comment: For other images did it work...The image is a pool game right.??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay its working for me. i have got the right image after i have decoded in the second activity. Just for checking i have an ImageView in Act1 and here i convert it into Base64String pass it as a string to Act2 and in Act2(in second activity i have a Android bot in the image view) i decode base 64 image and set the bitmap that i got decoding it.

**Code of first activity:**

```
public class ActivityImageBase64 extends Activity {

    ImageView ivOriginal;
    String imageInBase64;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_base64);

    ivOriginal = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivAct1);
    ivOriginal.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);


}


public void start(View v){


    mBitmap = ivOriginal.getDrawingCache(); 

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArray);
    byte[] byteArr = byteArray.toByteArray();  
    imageInBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(byteArr, Base64.DEFAULT);

    System.out.println(imageInBase64);

    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityImageBase64.this, ActivityImageBase64_2.class);
    intent.putExtra("image", imageInBase64);
    startActivity(intent);

}

}
```

**Code in Second Activity(decode the string to bitmap)**

```
public class ActivityImageBase64_2 extends Activity {


ImageView ivBase64Image;
private String base64Image;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_image_base64_2);

    ivBase64Image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivAndroidBot);
    base64Image = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");


    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(base64Image, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap base64Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0,
            decodedString.length);

    ivBase64Image.setImageBitmap(base64Bitmap);
}

}
```