# Call Image from Gallery/ImageButton to Canvas (DrawingView)

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-drawable, android-imagebutton

can anyone help me to solve this problem, how to call image from gallery/imagebutton to canvas for drawing?
this is my snippet code :

```
buah1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), BelajarMewarnai.class);
             startActivity(intent); 
        }   
    });
```

If anyone need a project I will send my project to email.

Comment: http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-pick-image-from-gallery/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890809/how-to-set-an-image-to-fill-a-canvas

Comment: U question is not understandable, do u want to pick an image from image gallery on a button click???

Comment: yes, i want pick a image from gallery/imagebutton to drawingview in another layout @DJphy

Comment: so you want to pick an image from sd card, or internal storage and load it in your imageView or canvas??

Comment: on How to transfer images from one activity to another see this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30407369/base64-image-conversion-in-android-resulting-in-corrupted-image/30432397#30432397

Comment: not like that sir @HawraaKhalil,i have some picture using imagebutton to showing and i mean is how to show picture from imagebutton to other layout for drawable. i cant speak spesific because i cant upload screenshot from my project, example (my screenshot) :
[IMG]http://i1296.photobucket.com/albums/ag13/Luthfi_Atma_Nugroho/Call%20image_zpsq2qrfd1s.jpg[/IMG][/URL]

Comment: okay, i got your point, you want to load(open) one of those images in the canvas in another activity, right? are those images already found in the application, in drawable or something?

Comment: yes sir @HawraaKhalil, that images already stored in drawable folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 buah1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),     BelajarMewarnai.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
//Get the image name you clicked on
            String imageName =     getResources().getResourceName(imageId);;
//Send the image name as a string, which you want      to load in the other activity
            bundle.putString("image_to_load", imageName.split("/")[1].toString());
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent); 
        }   
    });
```

then you can get your image name in the next activity in onCreate like this:

```
 //Here you can get the image name you already  clicked in the previous activity to load in your canvas
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                String image_name = bundle.getString("image_to_load")
        }
```

then you can set the image name to your imageView like this:

```
 //Here you can get all resources in res folder
     Resources res = getResources();
    //define a new string which takes the image name you get from extras in the above code
       String mDrawableName = image_name;
    //Now you have the image name you clicked in theprevious activity, and ResID is to get the resource id     from its name
        int resID = res.getIdentifier(mDrawableName, "drawable", getPackageName());
    //Here you can get the drawable from the   resourceID you obtained in the above line
       Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(resID );
    YOUR_IMAGE is the ImageView of the canvas you   want to load the image inside in order to draw or    whatever you want to do
      drawView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

I hope this will help..

Comment: have one account, example facebook,gmail or other. i have one question sir. @Hawraa Khalil

Comment: can you explain about

Resources res = getResources();
String mDrawableName = image_name;
int resID = res.getIdentifier(mDrawableName , "drawable", getPackageName());
Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(resID );
YOUR_IMAGE.setImageDrawable(drawable);

cause i don't know what the mean of YOUR_IMAGE bla bla bla

Comment: I will edit my code and add comments to explain the above,  and yes I have Facebook, just search for my name and u will get a picture for chess, its me

Comment: Please give me access to the project link to help you more, and update my answer to fit your question @LuthfiAtmaNugroho

Answer (score 2):

Actually i wanted to post the link in the comment for u but u seemed to bit less fimiliar with android(i thinking so), So i am posting my code to do that. First choose on which button click u want the user to be guided to gallery(only default gallery and not anything else, u may get a null pointer if u choose pic from any other).

**On that button click u do this:**

```
private void onClickOfButton(View v){

    Intent galleryIntent=new Intent();
    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "pic-select"), 10);//(10 its just a request code, u can give ur own, but same should there at receiving end )
}
```

Since u have started an activity for result, so u should be awaiting for a result from that started activity, so that activity will bring u the image and in ur activity u just collect it and put it into ur image view like this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if(requestCode==10 && resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK){
            try{

                Uri selectImageUri=data.getData();
                String selectedImagePath=getPath(selectImageUri);
                Bitmap pic=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
                if(pic!=null){
                    yourImageView.setImageBitmap(pic);

                }

            }catch(NullPointerException ex){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Go to default gallery area and choose a pic", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
        else
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

**The getPath method:**

```
private String getPath(Uri uri) {
    if( uri == null ) {
        return null;
    }
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if( cursor != null ){
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    return uri.getPath();
}
```

So this will do ur job...

Comment: [IMG]http://i1296.photobucket.com/albums/ag13/Luthfi_Atma_Nugroho/Call%20image_zpsq2qrfd1s.jpg[/IMG][/URL]